# HTML and CSS Table

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a table like in picture: [image]

Is it possible to achieve this with pure table (`tbody`,`th`,`td`,`tr`,`thead`) css, any example ? Generally I have trouble with rounded corners with border ?

Comment: Have you tried giving the table a `border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #000`?

Comment: Then it doesn't have rounded corners

Comment: Do you need `border-collapse: collapse` on the table?

Comment: @Ruddy And what exactly would he do there? Paste in his image and query for "Is it possible to achieve this with pure table"? It's not helpful to tell someone to Google something if they're not exactly sure how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @RGraham Really? Getting a table to look like that is something you can Google. Simply Google "Nice HTML CSS tables" and I'm sure you will find plenty of results that would give a answer.

Comment: Looking at the above that's not something *I* would have thought to have typed.

Comment: I would use div wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/XN82z/

Comment: @RGraham Uh huh. Just typing in "HTML table CSS" would do the trick. Like I said its not a hard thing to search. And it explains things a lot better then we will here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But there will be some issues regarding browser prefixes for some proprieties.

There is many ways to go around it , the best being using a css processor (eg: [compass](http://compass-style.org)).
or just google rounded corners and you will find what you looking for

Here is a [post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/rounded-corners/) discussing it in details.

so for the rounded corners this will be:

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
```

Regarding the alternating coloring you can use the css3 psudo-selector :

Please take look at this [post](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

this will work just fine but in older browsers this wont work so if you want to support older borwers use a seperate class for each .

```
.even-td {background: #CCC}
.odd-td {background: #FFF}
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ESa7r/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I wouldn't call unprefixed border-radius "future". Acording to http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius the only webkit remaining is iOS 3.2 and Android 2.1. There is no constance of -moz prefix, or konqueror prefix.

Comment: @vals this is just a copy and paste from the css-tricks .  i think by the time that article was written , it was future .

Answer (score 0):

To get rounded corners you can use css like (You must always collapse the border before making it round)

```
 table {
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-spacing: 0;
    }
    table, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

And for different colours you can do something like this.

```
    tr.d0 td {
    background-color: #CC9999; color: black;
}
tr.d1 td {
    background-color: #9999CC; color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr class="d0"><td>One</td><td>one</td></tr>
<tr class="d1"><td>Two</td><td>two</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLd8Z/1/) seems to work with just a border radius

```
table {
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: i think his question would also require cellspacing collapse on top of rounded corners